# SQL query optimization using dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization, common-table-expression, dynamicquery

[image: Execution plan][image: Execution Plan]I have the following stored procedure. It uses a common table expression and a table valued function. It takes 600 ms to execute this sp. I used dynamic query to avoid the use of a table valued function and the the execution time reduced to around 300 ms. Is it possible to further tune this select query so that the execution time comes down to around 100 ms.

--EXEC Sp_GetTripListByBusinesses 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,93', 1, 3, 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GetTripListByBusinesses]  
(  
 @BusinessID varchar (max),  
 @TripFlag int,  
 @TripFrom INT,  
 @IsAllTrip INT  
)  
AS  

BEGIN  
 DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max) = '';

     SET @Query= '
    ;With CTE  
     AS  
     (  
      select TripID, count(TripNotesID) as NoteCount from tripnotes  WHERE 
      TripNoteTypeID != 13 group by TripID  
     )  

    SELECT TRP.[TripID]  
     ,isnull(TRP.[AssignedTruckerID],0) as AssignedTruckerID  
     ,TRP.[BusinessID] AS BusinessID  
     ,isnull(TRP.[TruckRate],''0.0'') as TruckRate  
     ,TRP.[RequestedDatetime]  
     ,TRP.[ArrivedDatetime]  
     ,TRP.[DepartedDatetime]  
     ,TRP.[TripStatusID]  
     ,isnull(TRP.[IsDelayed] ,0) as IsDelayed  
     ,isnull(TRP.[IsStopped] ,0) as IsStopped  
     ,isnull(TRP.[RepeatUntilStop],'''') AS RepeatUntilStop  
     ,TRP.[ArrivedAtBusinessDatetime]  
     ,TRP.[OrgSiteID]  
     ,TRP.[OriginCustomerID] AS OrgCustomerID       
     ,OS.[SiteName] + '' / '' + ISNULL(OS.[AS400_ID],'''') AS OrgSiteName  
     ,isnull(OS.[SiteLat],''0.0'') as OrgSiteLat  
     ,isnull(OS.[SiteLong],''0.0'') as OrgSiteLong  
     ,isnull(OS.[WaypointsAvl],0) as OrgWaypointsAvl       
     ,isnull(OS.[NearestRoadwayLat],''0.0'') as OrgNearestRoadwayLat  
     ,isnull(OS.[NearestRoadwayLong],''0.0'') as OrgNearestRoadwayLong  
     ,OS.[SiteStatus] AS OrgSiteStatus  
     ,OS.[AS400_ID] AS OrgAS400_ID  
     ,TRP.[DestSiteID]  
     ,TRP.[DestCustomerID] AS DestCustomerID       
     ,DS.[SiteName] + '' / '' + ISNULL(DS.[AS400_ID],'''') AS DestSiteName  
     ,isnull(DS.[SiteLat],''0.0'') as DestSiteLat  
     ,isnull(DS.[SiteLong],''0.0'') as DestSiteLong       
     ,isnull(TRK.FirstName,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(TRK.[LastName],'''') AS 
      TruckerName  
     ,isnull(TRK.[TruckType],''A'') as TruckType  
     ,TRK.[Mobile] AS TruckerMobile  
     ,B.[Name] AS BusinessName  
     ,isnull(B.BusinessLat,''0.0'') as BusinessLat  
     ,isnull(B.BusinessLong,''0.0'') as BusinessLong  
     ,B.ContactNo AS BusinessContactNo  
     ,B.Address1 AS BusinessAddress1  
     ,B.Address2 AS BusinessAddress2  
     ,B.City AS BusinessCity  
     ,B.[State] AS BusinessState  
     ,B.Zip AS BusinessZip  
     ,TS.[StatusText]  
     ,CASE WHEN TA.[BillOfLading] IS NULL THEN ''NA'' ELSE ''BOL'' END AS 
      BillOfLading  
     ,CASE WHEN TA.[ScaleTicket] IS NULL THEN ''NA'' ELSE ''ST'' END AS 
      ScaleTicket  
     ,CASE WHEN TA.[OriginScaleTicket] IS NULL THEN ''NA'' ELSE ''OST'' END AS 
      OriginScaleTicket  
     ,TRP.OriginGrossBushels  
     ,TRP.DestGrossBushels  
     ,(SELECT count(TripNotesID) FROM dbo.[TripNotes]) as Notes  
     ,TRP.MainTripID  
     ,Convert(DATE, TRP.[RequestedDatetime]) AS TripDate  
     ,1 as TripOrderNo  
     ,isnull(TRP.IsSiteDelayed ,0) as IsSiteDelayed  
     ,TRP.CommodityID  
     ,C.CommodityName  
     ,CTE.NoteCount  
     ,TRP.InvoiceId  
     ,TRP.OneWayMiles as OneWayMile
     ,OS.SiteType AS OriginSiteType
     ,DS.SiteType AS DestSiteType
    FROM  dbo.[Trip] AS TRP  
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Site] AS OS ON TRP.OrgSiteID = OS.SiteID  
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Site] AS DS ON TRP.DestSiteID = DS.SiteID  
     LEFT JOIN dbo.[Trucker] AS TRK ON TRP.AssignedTruckerID = TRK.TruckerID AND ISNULL(TRK.TruckerStatus,''A'') = ''A''  
     LEFT JOIN dbo.[Commodity] as C ON TRP.CommodityID = C.CommodityID AND C.RecordStatus = ''A''  
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Business] AS B ON B.BusinessID = TRP.BusinessID  
     LEFT JOIN dbo.[TripStatus] AS TS ON TS.TripStatusID = TRP.TripStatusID  
     LEFT JOIN dbo.[TripAsset] AS TA ON TA.TripID = TRP.TripID  
     LEFT JOIN CTE ON CTE.TripID = TRP.TripID   
    WHERE   
     TRP.RecordStatus=''A'' and   
     TRP.BusinessID in (' +@BusinessID + ') 
    ORDER BY TRP.RequestedDatetime ASC';  

  execute sp_executesql @Query;

END
```

Comment: It depends on the size and structure of each table and on the existing indexes. You need to add the execution plan, in order to see where is the bottleneck.

Comment: I don't see anything dynamic about the above Stored Procedure. Are we missing something here? Also, you say you got around the table value function, which I assume is `StringtoIntConvertion`. If it's simply converting a `varchar` to an `int` what's wrong with `CONVERT` and `CAST`? Why use a TVF? (*Side note, it's conver**s**ion, not conver*t*ion.*)

Comment: What is the DDL of the function, `StringtoIntConvertion`? Perhaps that will show us the problem.

Comment: StringToIntConversion converts a comma separated string of integers into string and returns it as table. It takes time. So I used the above dynamic query. Removed the details in the comment as it exceeds the allowed number of characters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information, @BijuNB , don't put it in the comments.

Comment: What you have there, @BijuNB , is a ***huge*** injection issue. Imagine if someone ran this: `EXEC Sp_GetTripListByBusinesses N'1''); CREATE LOGIN NewSA WITH PASSWORD = ''ABC'', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER_ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewSA'; SELECT * FROM dbo.[Trip] AS TRP;', 1, 3, 1;` We still need that DDL for `StringtoIntConvertion`.

Comment: Also the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft and means **S**pecial **P**rocedure. Using it comes at a performance cost and can mean your Stored Proceduire will simply stop working in the future: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)